# How to delay the opening of the next form in VISUAL BASIC

Tags: vb.net

Here's my code. I just want to stop my form for a while so I can read the result first before it opens to the next form. Thank you!

```
    play_win.Text = winner
    com_win.Text = comwinner

    
    If winner >= 3 Then
        youarewinner.Show()

    ElseIf comwinner >= 3 Then
        youlose.Show()

    End If
```

Comment: Replace Show with ShowDialog?

Comment: Nothing happened, still the same. @GSerg

Comment: If that code is in an event handler, make the handler `async` and then `await Task.Delay([Delay])`, where `[Delay]` is the time to wait in milliseconds.

Answer (score -1):

play_win.Text = winner
com_win.Text = comwinner

```
If CInt(winner) >= 3 Then
    youarewinner.Show()

ElseIf CInt(comwinner) >= 3 Then
    youlose.Show()

End If
```